# Postman - can I save some of the cookie information returned in a variable?

Tags: postman

My first step is always the same - log in.  When I log in I need to get four pieces of information from the headers.  I then need to use those four cookies/values/whatever for subsequent actions (POST, PUT, GET, etc...)

Is there a way to save those four pieces of information from the headers into variables so that I can use them in my next query?  Since my session seems to time out after like 3 minutes all the copy and pasting is driving me mad.

I found this for the response body:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
```

How can I do something like that but for information returned in the header?

Answer (score 1):

if this is still an issue for you, you may have a look at this: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox
In paragraph "Request/response related properties" you have information on how to extract data from headers (request or response) and in the paragraph above, how to get data from cookies ...

hope this helps

Alexandre